# Java Swing layout, can't arrange elements

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I just started using Swing, because I need GUI for a program I'm trying to do, but I have a lot of difficulties in arranging things like I want. I tried to look on Oracle's site and also in some other place but I still don t understand how to do it.

The final layout that I want is something like this:

[image]

For now I don't have in mind specific dimension, just I want to look like this.

Can you help me guys giving me some tips on how to do this?

Comment: You say you *can't* arrange the elements. That means you must have tried something, which you should show in your question.

Comment: I'd probably use a `JSplitPane` for that.  What is supposed to happen if the GUI is stretched vertically - which component gets the extra space?

Comment: `JSplitPane`, or `JPanel` with a `GridBagLayout`. It all depends if you want to allow the user to modify the separation position between the top panel and the bottom panel.

Comment: have a look at TableLayout and/or MigLayout - they're the best i've worked with. About swing components, have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html

Comment: I'd look at a vertical `Box` with a `JList` on top and a `JTabbedPane` below.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has a really nice "WindowBuilder" feature.  You can use it to generate and place components.  Give it a try.  I think you will like it.  You can then study the generated code which will in turn, help you to increase your understanding of swing.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use MigLayout layout. It is both powerful and easy to use.